# DataGridView custom sort not on DataMember (Databound Grid)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a custom DataGridView column that uses an embedded control that pops up a search window for the value of that column.  The important thing is that the databound column is a numeric ID, but the custom column cells display a text description.

How do I get the column to sort on the text description rather than the numeric ID?

I don't see a way to override the column to sort by FormattedValue instead of Value.  I could ensure that the description shows up as a separate column in my data table, but I don't see any way to say "use column VALUE_ID as DataMember but column VALUE_DESCRIPITON as 'SortMember'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a technique described in the following article [Column Sort Modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95scxcdy.aspx)

```
private bool ascending;
private int sortColumn;
private void dgv_ColumnHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    List<SomeObject> list = (List<SomeObject>)someBindingSource.DataSource;
    if (e.ColumnIndex != sortColumn) ascending = false;

    int 1 = e.ColumnIndex;
    if (i == DescriptionColumn.Index)
        list.Sort(new Comparison<SomeObject>((x,y) => x.ID.CompareTo(y.ID)));

    sortColumn = e.ColumnIndex;
    ascending = !ascending;
    if (!ascending) list.Reverse():

    someBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    // you may also have to call dgv.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: A data table does not seem to be cast-able to a List<>

Comment: Although I could just set the sort directly on the binding source at that point -- I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 1):

What are you using as the data-source? a `DataTable`? The sort is most commonly provided by the list itself, so you could actually write a custom list with your own specific sort behaviour. The simplest approach (although still non-trivial) would be to inherit from `BindingList<T>`, and override `ApplySortCore`, `RemoveSortCore`, `SupportsSortingCore`, `IsSortedCore`, `SortPropertyCore` and `SortDirectionCore` (phew!). In particular, the `ApplySortCore` would have to detect the specific `PropertyDescriptor`, and perform the bespoke search.

I'm not saying it is trivial (quite the opposite) - but it can be done within the standard binding mechanisms.

An alternative idea might be to make the id something else, that isn't actually an int, but is a custom class/struct. It would need to implement `IComparable`/`IComparable<T>`, and have a `ToString()` that displays the desired text. Then you could presumably (untested) bind directly to that column.

However!!! If you aren't already familiar with `System.ComponentModel`, I would suggest avoiding this complexity. If the above makes sense, then fine - if not, I'm not sure I would attempt it for your first stab into that area...

Comment: Definitely not trivial!  But it seems like there might not be any faster way of doing this.